# Entity Framework - Distinct Facets - Performance Optimization

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, distinct

Suppose we have a complex generated query...

```
IQueryable<...> query = ... //something complex
```

And then I would like to return multiple "facets" and my current implementation is...

```
        var facets = new 
        {
            Countries = query.Select(r => new { Id = r.CountryId, Name = r.Country.Name })
                .Distinct().ToList(),
            Regions = query.Select(r => new { Id = r.RegionId, Name = r.Region.Name })
                .Distinct().ToList(),
            ... //7 more facets
        };
```

With this implementation I have 9 ToList() so I would have 9 db queries and since "query" is quite complex, it causes some performance issues. Is there any possibility to implement this with EF and a single db query?

Update: EF Core version 3.1

Comment: EF Core version?

Comment: EF Core version 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (EF Core 3.1) it's not possible to achieve the desired result shape with single database query.

What you can try though is to retrieve all the (distinct) data needed with single database query in memory and then retrieve the "facets" using LINQ to Objects. Basically splitting the query on server and client evaluation, which in pre EF Core 3.0 was implicit, and in EF Core 3.0+ has to be explicit.

e.g.

```
var data = query.Select(r => new 
{
    Country = new { Id = r.CountryId, Name = r.Country.Name }, // facet 1 data
    Region = new { Id = r.RegionId, Name = r.Region.Name }, // facet 2 data
    //... 7 more facets 
})
.Distinct() // with or w/o this depending on query performance vs result set size
.ToList();

var facets = new 
{
    Countries = data.Select(r => r.Country).Distinct().ToList(), // facet 1
    Regions = data.Select(r => r.Region).Distinct().ToList(), // facet 2
    //... 7 more facets
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I thought about this. And the third option is to just change all of that to stored procedure. For now, I'll just mark your answer, and hopefully EF will support this in the future.